# Import fails when Importing unmanaged solution to managed solution in CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

There are duplicate Business Rules in the Dynamics 365 unmanaged solution in the Development (organization) environment.

We are required to export Development as a managed solution (customizations are overwritten, Sdk Messaging is enabled) and import the solution into another Dynamics 365 environment known as the Test (organization) environment. Both the environments require us to log in with our credentials (example arommie).

Since Development has many duplicate business rules created and left behind by another team who transitioned to us.

Each time I import a solution from Dev into Test the import rolls back and the error log shows the following info:

> Error while importing workflow {7cfb65d9-966b-e911-b80c-00505683fbf4} type PortableBusinessLogic name "BUSINESS RULE ROMIE 1".

The import log screen showing the error on the first row

> A record with these values already exists. A duplicate record cannot be created. Select one or more unique values and try again..."

I have even tried by restoring the test environment, then importing Development into Test (managed). It deploys the first time without rolling back. Second time we tried deploying it rolls back.

I even tried to deactivate the duplicate Business rules. One duplicate business rules deactivates. The other duplicate business rules error out and will not allow me to deactivate them. These duplicate rules exist in the Production (organization) environment (managed).

**Note**: BUSINESS RULE ROMIE 1 is a sample name and implies a Business Rule.

Is there a quick solution fix you can suggest I can do to import the managed solution to Test without it failing and rolling back? The solution should also work while importing into the Production environment.

Comment: does the duplicate business rule in Test have the same ID? In that case try to delete it befor you import the corrected version. AND DONT DELETE SOMETHING WITHOUT A BACKUP OF SOME KIND

Comment: The IDs are different.

Comment: id={60348FBA-79FC-EB11-B82E-00505683D8C0}  id={AD50C8E6-EB14-EC11-B831-00505683D8C0} id={7CFB65D9-966B-E911-B80C-00505683FBF4}

Comment: Is this a microsoft D365 on premise product issue? Anyone experienced this.